# Method to show responsive divs side by side to fit whole space with margins in between them

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

I'm struggling to find a **reliable** solution to show any number of divs side by side to fit the whole space. They also need to have same height and size despite their content. The divs need to have some margin to separate one another. 
I cannot use Flex as the page I'm working on needs to be IE9 compatible. Hence, I'm relying on inline-block, floats and table methods.

Can you suggest anything?

Here is the HTML of what I've tried and the fiddle link for the full example --> https://jsfiddle.net/crvu1oc9/

```
<div class="cards-list">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-box">
        <img class="img-teaser" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg" alt="Card 1 image">
      </div>
      <div class="card__content-box">
        <div class="text-box">
          <h3>Choosing your elderly care at home</h3>
          <date>04 Nov, 2016</date>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-box">
        <img class="img-teaser" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg" alt="Card 1 image">
      </div>
      <div class="card__content-box">
        <div class="text-box">
          <h3>Choosing your elderly care at home</h3>
          <date>04 Nov, 2016</date>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-box">
        <img class="img-teaser" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg" alt="Card 1 image">
      </div>
      <div class="card__content-box">
        <div class="text-box">
          <h3>Choosing your elderly care at home</h3>
          <date>04 Nov, 2016</date>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and html samples so we can help you fix that code, otherwise this looks like you expect someone to write all the code for you ... and that's not how this site works. See [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I've tried a few things indeed. Let me attach something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS, give your each of your card classes a percentage that adds up to 100; since children inherit the width of parent elements, the percentages of all div's with class="card" will be added together.

width + padding + border + margin = total size

And so, in your case:

```
.cards-list{
            width: 90%;
            max-width: 980px;


        .card{
            float: left; /* or right */
            width: 32%;
            margin-right: 1.333333%;
```

Since you have only 3 elements with the card class, this will fill up the entire card-list div element. 32% width + 1.33% margin-right = 33.33% / card.

When you add elements, recalculate the percentages.

Here is your code working with four "card"'s: https://jsfiddle.net/crvu1oc9/1/

Comment: @wIh thanks for your answer. That's what I was doing basically. But when I add more text to one of the cards the height of the other cards look different. I tried to use "display:table" and "table-cell" to have all cards look equal. The problem with the table like approach is that I cannot add the 'right-margin" ONLY in between them. The margin gets added around each card and cannot find a way to add it only to its right.

Comment: The only way to keep the height uniform will be to set the height on the class level. If you add text that creates another line, that particular box will increase in height. Have you looked into using something like bootstrap [link](http://getbootstrap.com) where you could use their grid to keep things in line?

Comment: I wanted to find a solution without using neither grid nor flex methods. It seems like that there's no solution for this unless setting each div height?